# Missing query for request id: undefined Google Visualization

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to make a simple page with search bar when a user searches a particular word the data is to be pulled from google spread sheets

```
var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B, C, D, E,F where A like "%<?php echo $search; ?>%" or B like "%<?php echo $search; ?>%" or C like "%<?php echo $search; ?>%" or D like "%<?php echo $search; ?>%" or E like "%<?php echo $search; ?>%" label A "Sr no", B "Product name", C "Technical name", D "Category", E "Seller Name", F "Price" ');
```

This works while

```
var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B, C, D, E,F where upper(A) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or B like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or C like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or D like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or E like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") label A "Sr no", B "Product name", C "Technical name", D "Category", E "Seller Name", F "Price" ');
```

This does not. Just trying to make the query case insensitive.

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you just need to add `upper` to the rest of the columns

you added `upper(A)` for column A

but *not* for the rest of the columns -- B,C,D, & E

i.e.

`B like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%")`

vs.

`upper(B) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%")`

**second line from question**

`var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B, C, D, E,F where upper(A) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or B like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or C like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or D like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or E like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") label A "Sr no", B "Product name", C "Technical name", D "Category", E "Seller Name", F "Price" ');`

**change to this...**

`var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B, C, D, E,F where upper(A) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or upper(B) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or upper(C) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or upper(D) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or upper(E) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") label A "Sr no", B "Product name", C "Technical name", D "Category", E "Seller Name", F "Price" ');`

Comment: is `A "Sr no"` a numeric column or string? if numeric, `upper(A)` will not work.

Comment: Hey thanks man... That was the exact issue :) it worked thank you